# Unknown annotations are not ignored in Class.getAnnotations on Android Jelly Bean

Tags: java, android, annotations

**Problem**

According to [JSR-175](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=175#updates) java specification if annotation is not available in the runtime it should be silently ignored. But on Android API 15-16 calling `getDeclaredAnnotations()` causes `NoClassDefFoundError` exception. On API 17+ it is working as expected without exception.

Check example project below for details.

**Question**

What workaround would you suggest?
Do you know about the related Android bug report? I couldn't find one.

**Example**

We have a sample class with `@Nullable` annotation:

```
public class SampleClass {
   @Nullable
   private String _content;
}
```

`@Nullable` is available during the build process, but we exclude it from the apk (to cut method count), in the example we do it like this:

```
configurations {
   provided
}

android.applicationVariants.all {
   variant -> variant.javaCompile.classpath += configurations.provided
}

dependencies {
   provided group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', name: 'jsr305', version: '3.0.2'
}
```

In the `MainActivity` we try to get all annotations from the `_content` field:

```
Class clazz = SampleClass.class;
Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField("_content"); 
Annotation[] annotations = field.getDeclaredAnnotations(); // this line is throwing exception on API 15-16
```

As a result we get and exception on Android API 15-16:

```
11-24 17:06:49.874 2146-2146/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/Nullable
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.getDeclaredAnnotations(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.getDeclaredAnnotations(Field.java:204)
        at im.getsocial.checkannotation.MainActivity.checkReflection(MainActivity.java:26)
        at im.getsocial.checkannotation.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        ...
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.Nullable
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.getDeclaredAnnotations(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.getDeclaredAnnotations(Field.java:204) 
        at im.getsocial.checkannotation.MainActivity.checkReflection(MainActivity.java:26) 
        at im.getsocial.checkannotation.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
        ...
```

The complete sample project is available here: http://take.ms/Li3NF

Interesting that Java 5 had similar issue reported: http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6322301

**Updates**

- Jan 27: samplified example and fixed compile errors

Comment: Looks like you're removing wrong @Nullable. In the sample class you're using javax.annotation.Nullable and in your build config you're excluding android.support.annotation.Nullable, so you should try to use correct one. Or I'm not fully understand your question?

Comment: Yup, sorry, included the wrong project. Now the example is simplified and compile issues fixed.

Comment: i tried to paste your build.gradle of App code but it is giving error Error:Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Resolving configuration 'provided' directly is not allowed

Comment: My minimum api version is 16

Comment: @VívêkBåräì did you try to run demo app?